# Rails 4 array.include? issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, string

Hi i have a function to check if the current controller + action is included in array list but its not working here is my code

Function

```
    def verify
      cur_path = params[:controller] +'/'+ params[:action]
      confirm_access(cur_path)
    end

    def confirm_access(section)
     user_group = UserGroup.find(1)
     allowed_acl = Array.new
     user_group.access_sections.each do |d|
      allowed_acl << d.section
     end
      if allowed_acl.include? section
        return true
      else
        #false
      end
    end
```

But when I pass confirm_access("string") static string it is working but not with cur_path variable.

Comment: where is `allowed_acl` coming from?

Comment: a bit offtopic: your `confirm_access` method could contain just the line `allowed_acl.include? section`. There's no need to wrap it in `if .. return ... else return ...`

Comment: @mr rogers Please check now I've included `allowed_acl`  array

Comment: Is it about a leading `/`?  That is, does `UserGroup#access_sections` return something like `/controller_name/action_name` or `controller_name/action_name`?

Comment: @mr rogers yes exactly i want `controller_name/action_name` but I will use this function for different controller thats why i am using `params[:controller]`

Comment: Right - but can you show us what `UserGroup#access_sections` returns?  I assume an array of strings, but how are they constructed?  Do they have a leading `/` that is messing up the string matching?  Maybe you can include the return value from `UserGroup.find(1).access_sections` for clarity.

Comment: @mr rogers UserGroup.find(1).access_sections returns me hash array  `[#<AccessSection id: 24, section: "admin/dashboard/index", created_at: "2015-01-01 19:19:58", updated_at: "2015-01-01 19:19:58", user_id: 1>`  then I push section indexes to new array `allowed_acl`, as i mention in question if I put static string at `if allowed_acl.include? 'admin/dashboard/index'` it is working.

Comment: I also tried to inspect and `cur_path` which contains controller#action it is passing as argument in `confirm_access` method.

Comment: Thanks @mr rogers I solved it.
First I created a new variable called `myvar = section` and added beside include? it is now working as it should be.

Comment: So maybe you were overwriting `section` or the scoping was wrong?  Check out my answer.  If you simplified your methods, it might have been easier to debug in the first place.   Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really hard to figure out what is not going right.  On the surface, it seems like it should be working fine.

I wonder if you simplified the code a bit then you might be able to debug things better.

For one, you could add a method to UserGroup that gives you the `acls` you want.

```
class UserGroup < ActiveRecord::Base

   ...

   def allowed_acl
     access_sections.map(&:section)
   end

end
```

Then your controller methods become much simpler

```
def verify
  cur_path = params[:controller] +'/'+ params[:action]
  confirm_access(cur_path)
end

def confirm_access(section)
  UserGroup.find(1).allowed_acl.include? section
end
```

It seems like at this point, you should be able to look at the list of allowed ACL's and make sure that the match you expect to happen is happening.  I mocked this up (outside of Rails) and it all seems to be working fine.